# Как можно выставить сетку между стобцами датафрейма пандас?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns. I need to visualise my df like in the screenshot

(У меня есть датафрейм с колоннами, Мне нужно визуализировать данные как на скрине ниже.) [image: output I need]
And this is my output

(Это мой вывод, который я получаю просто делая print(df))[image: my output]
And my question is how to add a grid in pandas and hide the index column?

(Мой вопрос состоит в том, как добавить сетку между полями и скрыть колонну ИНДЕКС?)
I need to visualise it in CMD(Windows)/Terminal(MacOS)

(Визуализация должна отображаться в Командной строке или Терминале МакОС)

Входные данные вводятся через командную строку и парсятся через argparse в коде
Пример входных данных:

deposit --client="John Jones" --amount=100 --description="ATM Deposit"

withdraw --client="John Jones" --amount=100 --description="ATM Deposit"

show_bank_statement --client="John Jones" --since="2021-01-01 00:00:00" --till="2021-02-01
00:00:00"

(deposit, withdraw, show_bank_statement) - методы класса, которые я вызываю для выполнения (пополнения счета, снятия со счета и вывода транзакций за определенный период) соответственно
В частности, именно последний метод выводит в командную строку данные приведенные в скриншоте выше. И именно эти данные нужно привести к виду первого скриншота

```
    def show_bank_statement(self, client, since, till):
        df = DF[(since < DF['Date']) & (DF['Date'] < till)]
        DF_ind = DF.index[DF.Date >= since][0]
        total_with, total_dep, last_balance = pd.to_numeric(df['Withdrawals'], errors='coerce').sum(
        ), pd.to_numeric(df['Deposits'], errors='coerce').sum(), list(df['Balance'])[-1]
        df = df.append({'Date': '',
                        'Description': 'Totals',
                        'Withdrawals': total_with,
                        'Deposits': total_dep,
                        'Balance': last_balance},
                        ignore_index=True)
        df.loc[0] = ['', 'Previous balance', '', '', DF['Balance'][DF_ind]]
        pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
        pd.set_option('display.float_format', '${:.2f}'.format)
        t = from_csv(StringIO(df.to_csv(index=False)))
        print(t)
```

Это участок кода на вывод данных, где since и till - даты для установки диапозона вывода

Попытался использовать предложенные варианты и менять форматы данных, так ничего и не добился. Но спасибо за ответы, все варианты я учту для будущих работ, так как впервые сталкиваюсь с визуализацией таблиц определенным способом

Comment: воспользуйтесь модулем `prettytable` или `DataFrame.to_html()`

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 6):

Пример:

```
In [171]: df
Out[171]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

In [172]: from prettytable import from_csv

In [173]: from io import StringIO

In [174]: t = from_csv(StringIO(df.to_csv(index=False)))

In [175]: print(t)
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: после 124К счётчик останавливается ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, не уверен что понял вас... Какой счетчик?

Comment: 124к - я плюс поставил а 124к осталось

Comment: @MaximLensky, теперь понял! 124k - это округленное значение в тысячах ("k" - кило) :)

Comment: я на en.so 324 видел - хоть бы на тугрики их обменять можно было :))

Comment: К сожалению, мои значки $ пропадают и формат чисел уходит в обычный флоат с этим вариантом.
А также необходимо отделить первую и последнюю строку датафрейма "Previous Balance" и "Totals" их индексы всегда будут равны [0] и [-1] соответственно

Comment: pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
        
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '${:.2f}'.format)

Этими командами привожу сам датафрейм в нужный мне формат

Comment: @David, я не просто так [попросил привести в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1280176/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%81/1280191?noredirect=1#comment2255704_1280176) (в комментарии под вопросом) [mcve] ;)

Comment: @MaxU Да, я просто подумал, что скрины помогут в понимании вопроса. Так как код у меня в 120 строк и выделение именно данных с форматом не объяснило бы работу.
Но сейчас добавлю, может это поможет